# Derive $P(A|C)$ from $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|C)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm working myself through renormalization theory (doesn't matter) and made up a problem to solve for myself, where in the solution seem to be missing one step, which can be summarized as follows:

For discrete random variables $A$, $B$ and $C$ and known conditional probabilities $P(A=i|B=j)$ and $P(B=j|C=k)$, I'd like
to say something about $P(A=i|C=k)$ (the 'coarse graining'). My intuition says it should look something
like

$$
P(A=i|C=k) = \sum_j P(A=i|B=j) P(B=j|C=k)
$$

, a sum over all possible `paths' from C to A over B to integrate out B. It seems to check out if I plug in some numbers, but I'm unable to prove this to be true using the chain rule, definition of the conditional probability or bayesian rule. What am I missing?

Comment: this assumes A is independent from C given B

Comment: That makes sense. Would a nice closed form exist if A is not independent from C given B?